# group-hover not working for Tailwind (even with default variants)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwind's group-hover is not working in my project. I'm trying to change text color, on hover of parent div.

I'm using with react.

```
<div class="group">
   <div>
     <div class="group-hover:text-blue">Hover me</div>
     <div class="group-hover:text-red">Hover me</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Above is my code where I need to change **textColor **by using configs in **tailwind.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

   variants: {
   textColor: ['group-hover', 'hover'],
 }
  // ...
}
```

I've also tried with below, but no luck. :(

```
textColor: ['responsive', 'dark', 'group-hover', 'focus-within', 
 'hover', 'focus'],
```

and

```
 textColor: ['group-hover'],
```

Comment: Consider checking the file that the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: yes, It's included.

Answer (score 0):

text-blue, and text-red only works if you have defined those colors in tailwind configuration file.

Try this instead,

```
<div class="group">
   <div>
     <div class="group-hover:text-blue-700">Hover me</div>
     <div class="group-hover:text-red-700">Hover me</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I have defined both colors.